# Pygame 1.9.2 ImportError:DLL load failed

Tags: dll, windows-7, import, pygame, python-3.3

I am newbie for PyGame and I wish to use it. 
I have a Win7 32-bit machine with Python3.3.0

I carefully chose the correct installer and used it to install PyGame.
Installation finished with no errors. I thought everything is fine. Restarted my PC several times. Then I started with typing "import pygame":

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried to solve my problem with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969426/pygame-in-windows-importerror-dll-load-failed) article. But he/she is using python 2.6.4 and chose the installer for 2.6. I picked up [that](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi) installer. Am I using the wrong one? If I am right, why I can't import it? I tried that article's resources and advices. I know that PyGame has python3 support now. Why can't I use it?

Answer (score 0):

https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads

download it into the location with the other libraries that are downloaded when python is downloaded