# Not able to import Python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not able to install any packages 
I've tried VLC package from https://wiki.videolan.org/python_bindings
and got a traceback.

Now I am trying pygame module and this is what i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\pygame\__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Please help i am pretty new to python

Comment: Have you tried pip install pygame?

Comment: yes i did , here it is


C:\Users\Vineeth\Downloads>pip install pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pygame==1.9.3 from file:///C:/Users/Vineeth/Downloads/pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl in c:\users\vineeth\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib

Comment: Try checking out this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to execute your statements and the imports worked fine for me. I have a 64bit `Windows OS`. And my python version `Python 3.5.2` - 64bit.

Check if you have other Python versions, if you have removed them, make sure you did that right.

Ultimately I would just suggest you to do `pip install pygame`. The version compatibility will be handled by `pip` itself.

Comment: I tried pip then i get this error



C:\Users\Vineeth\Downloads>pip install pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pygame==1.9.3 from file:///C:/Users/Vineeth/Downloads/pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl in c:\users\vineeth\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib

Comment: Only type out `pip install pygame`. Don't add any additional information.

Comment: yea i did the same thing , But its not working , whenever i type import pygame in python IDLE 

I get the same error again

Comment: What is your OS configuration and Python configuration?  Perform `pip uninstall pygame` and then try to install `pip install pygame`. Also open the command prompt as administrator.

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit and Python 3.6

Comment: cant upvote :( I still dont have 15 rep , but accepted the answer!

Comment: @VineethSai Also in the future, it is best to just `pip install [modulename]`. And certain privileges that don't work unless you Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

There are some release binaries for Python3.x, 64bit Windows at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

I suggest you download it from that site and install it. It works for me. If you are using Windows ,it is a good way to install some packages,like `lxml` `matplotlib`.

Also you check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969426/pygame-in-windows-importerror-dll-load-failed).

Hope this helps.