# How to fix import error in python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I am getting error when import any python library or module.

the following error shown by IDE:

```
  from pygame.base import * # pylint: disable=wildcard-import; lgtm[py/polluting-import]
  Import error: DLL load failed while importing base: The specified procedure could not be found
```

Additional information:
python version = 3.9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pygame in Windows: ImportError: DLL load failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969426/pygame-in-windows-importerror-dll-load-failed)

Comment: No, because I am not only getting error in pygame library, but also in other library and module

Comment: How did you install pygame?

Comment: By using command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pygame
```

Comment: DLLs are a windows thing.